# Exchange 2016 Block IP after too many Failed Login Attemps

Tags: exchange

I would like to block an ip address if I see too many failed login attempts from it. 
I would like to block SMTP,OWA,IMAP and POP3 failed login attemps.
I don't want to block user account but the ip.
Is that possible in Exchange 2016.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the [exchange server powershell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-server/open-the-exchange-management-shell?view=exchange-ps).

Permanently

```
Add-IPBlockListEntry -IPAddress 192.168.0.100
```

or with an expiration time

```
Add-IPBlockListEntry -IPRange 192.168.0.1/24 -ExpirationTime "1/3/2013 23:59"
```

Details: [Add-IPBlockListEntry](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/antispam-antimalware/add-ipblocklistentry?view=exchange-ps)

Comment: This is the manual way, I have to check the logs and block an ip. I would like the exhange do this automatic is that possilbe?

Comment: No, there is no built-in feature in Exchange can achieve your requirement to automatic block IPs based on the number of failed logon attempts.